# How to stop eventmachine when using multiple requests

Tags: ruby, events, asynchronous, callback, eventmachine

I am making batch calls to an API via HTTP using EventMachine and em-http-requests

I am unsure of how stop the event machine with EM.Stop after all the callbacks are complete

Supposing I make 10 async batch calls, how do i stop the eventmachine right after I am done with the 10th callback?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example from the `em-http-request` GitHub page](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/blob/master/examples/fetch.rb). It does exactly what you want.